# TypeScript type comparison Type 'Site | Site[]' is not assignable to type 'Site'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following interfaces

```
export interface Site {
  id: number;
  path: string;
  siteLink: string;
  features: Feature[];
}

export interface SiteResponse {
  data: Site | Site[];
  meta?: any;
}
```

That's being used because I may retrieve an object or an array of objects. Depends on API route I call.

And here is my service's method I try work with

```
getSiteById(id: number): Observable<SiteResponse> {
    return this.http.get<SiteResponse>(this.API_URL + '/' + id);
  }
```

And it's subscription

```
this.ss.getSiteById(this.id).subscribe((x: SiteResponse) => {
        const site: Site = x.data;

        this.link.setValue(site.siteLink);
        this.imagePreview = site.path;
        site.features.forEach(feature => {
          this.features.push(this.fb.control(feature, Validators.required));
        });
        this.isPending = false;
      });
```

For me it looks OK, but not for the validator.

> error TS2322: Type 'Site | Site[]' is not assignable to type 'Site'. Type 'Site[]' is not assignable to type 'Site'. Property 'id' is missing in type 'Site[]'.

Comment: What is `const site: Site = x.data;` supposed to do when `x.data` is a `Site[]`?

Comment: It isn't. X is a `SiteResponse` which contains `data` either `Site[]` or `Site`. In this case `Site`

Comment: Is the fact that this particular SiteResponse will contain only Site, and not Site[] something that the type system should be able to infer? How could it know that `this.http.get<SiteResponse>(this.API_URL + '/' + id);` should not produce a SiteResponse with a Site[]?

Comment: I've specified for typescript that it will contain one of the possible types. I see no problem. Multiple type definitions are created for that purpose

Comment: To produce a `Site | Site[]`, you can produce either a Site    or produce a Site[], but if someone hands you a `Site | Site[]`, you can't just assume it's a Site.  The documentation has some examples of checking which alternative you recieved: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: They also use `|`. Moreover, I've explicitly specified that should be at the outcome. Therefore, `Site` should pass `Site | Site[]` since it does exist in type.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding extra type declaration
`const site: Site = <Site>x.data;`